# Speechsynthesizer (System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer) - Changing the volume or rate at runtime

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, sapi, speech-synthesis

```
string TextToBeRead = "My sample text";
SpeechSynthesizer speaker = new SpeechSynthesizer();
speaker.Rate = 5;
speaker.Volume = 70;
speaker.SpeakAsync(TextToBeRead);
```

Is there any way to change the rate or volume, once the speaker starts talking? I have tried to change it at runtime but output still uses old rate and volume. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET Text To Speech Volume](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444081/net-text-to-speech-volume)

Comment: According to the linked question, "While the text is being read, the volume cannot be changed"

Answer (score 2):

No you can't change it while it's reading but you can subscribe to [`SpeakProgress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakprogress(v=vs.110).aspx) event so you can get the [`CharacterPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.speech.synthesis.speakprogresseventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) and restart speak with a new rate and volume at given position

Answer (score 1):

You can do this inline using the SSML [prosody element](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/#S3.2.4), and the rate and volume attributes.

You'll need to use the [SpeakSsmlAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakssmlasync(v=vs.110).aspx) method on SpeechSynthesizer to make this work.